# MongoDB find a given field and get average value

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'd like to get the average in a collection for a given property value. What am I doing wrong?

```
[{name:'Bob',city:'Barcelona',trips: 1 },
{name:'Bruce',city:'Barcelona',trips: 5 },
{name:'Bruno',city:'València',trips: 2 },
{name:'Bart',city:'Barcelona',trips: 3 }]

db.x.aggregate([{$group:{city:'Barcelona', $avg:"$trips"}}]);
```

Comment: db.x.aggregate([{$group:{_id:city, $avg:"$trips"}}]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter the documents using the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** operator i.e. create a pipeline before the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** operator which will filter all the documents in the collection based on the given city value.

In the preceding **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** operator pipeline, you can then use a null key (as denoted by the `_id` field) to group all the documents from the previous pipeline and get the accumulated average:

```
db.x.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "city": "Barcelona" } },
    { "$group": { "_id": null, "$avg": "$trips" } }
]);
```

---

Another approach (not as optimal as the above) would be to group all the documents in the collection by the city key and then filter afterwards:

```
db.x.aggregate([
    { "$group": { "_id": "$city", "$avg": "$trips" } },
    { "$match": { "_id": "Barcelona" } }
]);
```